# How to get input stream of contents of a zip file?

Tags: java, zip, inputstream

I have a input stream of a zip file which i will get it from a web service response. This zip file contains one XML file. I need to extract the input stream of this XML file from the input stream of the zip file. Please help.I have tried the below code.But no success.

```
DataHandler dataHandler = odDocClient.getUniqueDoc(null, null);
inputStream = dataHandler.getInputStream();
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
ZipEntry zipEntry=zipInputStream.getNextEntry();            
File tempZipFile= new File("D:\\WorkSpace\\Invoicing\\ZIP\\tempZip1.zip");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream= new FileOutputStream(tempZipFile);
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, fileOutputStream);
inputStream.close();
inputStream.close();
fileOutputStream.close();
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(tempZipFile); 
inputStream=zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);
```

this input stream will be used further.

With the above code i am getting the following exception.

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:159)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Here variable "is" is your inputstream, For time bean I cast long to int in array size but in your code you have to read stream properly.

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);        
ZipEntry ze;
    while((ze=zis.getNextEntry()) != null){
        if(!ze.isDirectory() && ze.getName().endsWith(".xml")) {                
            byte[] arr = new byte[(int)ze.getSize()]; // an array of size in zip entry
            zis.read(arr);
            // Your contains is here 
            System.out.println(new String(arr));
        }
}
```